# Is Tag Synonyms Privilege Missing at FAQ Page?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, faq-update-request

I just reached 2500 reputation at main stackoverflow site and gained `Adding Tag Synonyms` privilege. There is a description page at the wiki about `What is Tag Synonyms?` but I couldn't find it at `FAQ->What is reputation?` section.

> 2000 Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested
>   edits
>
> 3000 Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions

There is no 2500. Is there a reason for that or is it just missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ reports just a part of the privileges, probably the most important. As a matter of fact, it doesn't report the "set bounties" privilege either.

There is no probably point on reporting all the privileges on the FAQ page, considering that the FAQ already has a link to [the privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

[image: screenshot]